# Api Platform : When to use DTO and when to use serialization groups?

Tags: php, symfony4, api-platform.com

I need to return an user from the api. My user entity have some basics attributes :

- email
- username
- password

But I don't want to return the password in the json response.

Currently I see 2 possibilities to remove it from the output :

- Using a [serialization groups](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#using-serialization-groups)
- Using [DTO](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/)

I would like to know the right way, when to use the serialization groups and when to use DTO (pros and cons).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove password serialization groups are appropriate.

- Groups are the easiest way to add or remove attributes
- DTO can be used for an even better control but I don't know any use case.

So basically just add `normalizationContext={"groups"={"user_read"}}` in your ApiPlatform annotation and specify `@Groups({"user_read"})` for readable attributes.

Comment: A use case of a DTO could be a report that has different output then the entities it is about, see chapter 9 of my [turorial](https://github.com/metaclass-nl/tutorial-api-platform). Another if there is a POST [operation without an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64744246/operation-without-entity) that primarily DOES something that has output different from the input.