# API Platform Collection POST Operation without Item GET

Tags: api-platform.com

I want to create a resource with collection operations "POST" and "GET" and no item operations.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "get",
 *          "post"
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={}
 * )
 */
```

When I try to post an item I get the following error: "No item route associated with the type App\Entity\MyEntity".

I seems like API Platform is trying to create an IRI but it can't because there is no item "GET" operation.

I do not need an IRI, the plain Id would be fine for me. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: I found a solution in the documentation: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#enabling-and-disabling-operations

I can disable the GET operation like this:

```
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get"={
 *             "controller"=NotFoundAction::class,
 *             "read"=false,
 *             "output"=false,
 *         },
 *     },
```

However it does not return a 404 like the documentation says. Instead it returns a 500 error with message "Controller NotFoundAction does neither exist as service nor as class.". How can I get it to return 404.

Also it would be nice if the GET operation would not show up in my Swagger documentation.

EDIT: I found my mistake with the 404. I forgot to include `use ApiPlatform\Core\Action\NotFoundAction;`

Now I just need a way to remove the route from my documentation.

EDIT: I used a Swagger decorater to remove the route from the docs.

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Swagger;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

final class SwaggerDecorator implements NormalizerInterface
{
    private NormalizerInterface $decorated;

    public function __construct(NormalizerInterface $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, string $format = null): bool
    {
        return $this->decorated->supportsNormalization($data, $format);
    }

    public function normalize($object, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $docs = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);

        unset($docs['paths']['/products/{id}']);

        return $docs;
    }
}
```

And in services.yaml:

```yaml
App\Swagger\SwaggerDecorator:
        decorates: 'api_platform.swagger.normalizer.documentation'
        arguments: [ '@App\Swagger\SwaggerDecorator.inner' ]
        autoconfigure: false
```

My solution works but I am not sure if it is the best solution. So if any one has another idea, feel free to answer.

Comment: I suppose apip wants to serialize the result of your POST operation and that is by default assumed to be an instance of your resource. Because it is a resource, it wants to make an iri for it. If the result of your POST is a DTO it does not have to be a resource, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64744246/operation-without-entity).